# What's the advantage of [insert your favorite logging library here] over System.Diagnostics.Trace?

Tags: .net, logging, system.diagnostics

Apologies if I overlooked it but I couldn't immediately find a similar question on SO.

.Net comes with some built-in logging capabilities (essentially, System.Diagnostics.Debug and System.Diagnostics.Trace).

Is there a good reason not to use these built-in facilities for logging purposes in a typical LOB application, and instead use log4net, NLog, EntLib logging block or [insert your favourite logging library here]?

EDIT: note that I am more interested in pinpointing the shortcomings of System.Diagnostics w.r.t. logging capabilities, rather than the features of the different logging libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use NLog or log4net because it gives me:

1. Logging targets. I can chose the best for certain purpose without changing any bit of logging code
2. I can log the informations that I need at certain situation thanks to Log Levels
3. I can format my Log Entry the way I like, also in different ways for diferent Targets
4. Performance is quite ok, thanks for batching
5. Im not inventing the wheel
6. I can reause this many times

Comment: Most of these items also count for System.Diagnostics.Trace, no?

Comment: @jeroenh. For 1: using NLog you have more than 20 target OUT OF THE BOX. Using Trance: you can implement more of this by your own, but it's monkey coding. For 2nd: I can manage souce->target without recompiling my code, don't now if its possible using Trace. For 3rd: Formaters for Trace? For 4rd: Tracing should be DISABLED in production environment due performance reasons. For 5th: writing your own TraceListeners y'r doing monkey coding. For 6th: It's depends of your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Being able to send your logs to multiple endpoints (syslog, database, event log, etc) can be useful.

Comment: Is this not possible with System.Diagnostics? What about TraceListeners?

Answer (score 1):

I use log4net and it's advantages are that in configuration files you can choose what level of logging you require (Critical, Error, Warning, Information, Debug) and you get things like email logging and rolling log files for free.

Comment: about the logging level: how is this not possible with Diagnostics.Trace? There are different levels there too, right (TraceInformation, TraceWarning, ...)

Comment: A quick search revealed that several SMTP tracelisteners are available (a.o. one in the EntLib); I give you that with log4net it's built in though.

Answer (score 0):

For .net, I like using http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/doc-latest/reference/html/logging.html.  It's basically a wrapper layer above, so underneath, you can switch logging engines easily.  It's very log4net like though.

There is also:

http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html

Comment: What features does this provide that are not available with System.Diagnostics.Trace?